# Deploying DAC Package to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools, data-tier-applications

Im new in SSDT and faced with the following problem:

In VS 2012 I have created new Database Project and added few Tables. SQL Server 2008 was selected as target platform. Then I made project snapshot and tried to deploy it on 2008R2 SP2 server.

In the SQL Management Studio, after selecting the .dacpac file in the wizard I got the error: 
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/Serialization/2012/02'> was not expected. (opnsd5i2)

I can deploy this package to 2012 server without any problems, but my goal is development of database for 2008R2 server.

Comment: Have you tried publishing directly from your project to the server? Using SQLPackage to push the changes in the dacpac to the server? http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/01/ssdt-publishing-and-referenced-databases.html

Comment: Yes I have, and it works normal, but I want to store separate snapshots for each commit with db changes. I also can't publish directly to production server.

Comment: You can still snapshot each one, but if you use SQLPackage to push the changes or generate the scripts from that saved dacpac, you should be fine. We do that regularly - build the dacpac; separate process calls SQLPackage to publish it (and generate the script). Our Jenkins server actually does the changes to the production server through the build/publish process.